# Is it possible to import files from another computer using glob in Python3.4?

Tags: python, input, ssh, stream, glob

I would like to use some .pkl files for this program I am creating. However the files are about 1.1 GB and there are a lot of them so I needed to store them on a larger space(which I do not have sudo permissions for). I would like to do something like this:

```
for file in glob.glob('/home/jdoe/data/serializedpiondata/'):
    '''Code''' ...
    ...
    ...
```

However the file are not located on my computer but rather a computer I have access to via SSH. Is it possible to perform a similar operation but grab the files from a directory on another computer?

Comment: A lot depends on what bandwidth you have to the remote system, and which services you can make use of to access it. For example, if it runs an NFS server process then you could "simply" mount the appropriate file system remotely and access the files in exactly the same way as you do local files. Presumably you have room to store at least one at a time if you are prepared to copy them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by mounting the remote computer to the local filesystem using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) or something similar. At the OS level, you mount the remote system just like any other disk, and within Python, you would access it like you would any other local file. Since all traffic goes over ssh (and the internet?) assume some lag of course.

Comment: wow that's very useful so all I do is run `sshfs hostname:mountpoint` and I'm good to go.

Comment: Basically, yes. Exact implementation may depend on which OS you are using, and this is a Linux only thing. You'll probably want to add a line to your fstab file so it would get automatically mounted on boot.

Comment: A search for `<your linux distro> sshfs fstab` should find what you need.

Comment: well for macs OSXFUSE will do the same thing correct? Only asking because my work computer does not have glib2.0 nor its dependencies so I would rather just use the OSXFUSE and have that nice UI installer instead of doing everything by hand on my Linux distro

Comment: I've never used it, but it sounds like it should work.